# Android Imageview auto scroll with an animation

Tags: android, imageview

I have a image(size is 600 * 400) and my imageview size is (300 * 400).

I want load this image and auto scroll from left to right (in 5 seconds) with an animation.

I try to use "scrollto" and timer but It's not very good.

How to smooth scroll this imageview with an animation ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use Handler?

```
Handler handler1 = new Handler(); 
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                    "Your code that be executed after 5 seconds"
                 } 
            }, 5000);
```